# Put a black box image over existing video using ffmpeg

Tags: windows, opencv, ffmpeg, blob

I am using blob tracker, but have a timecode on video files. I want to overlay a black box over it, therefore preventing the timecode interfering with the tracker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going by [the FFmpeg docs for overlay](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#overlay-1), you're going to want something like:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i in -vf "color=black:20x10 [over]; [in][over] overlay=5:5 [out]" out
```

Replacing `20x10` and `5:5` with the width x height of the box and the position of the timestamp as necessary.